# How to determine if a category ID is a descendant of the top parent category

Tags: php, wordpress

If the current category that the user is viewing is a descedant of a specific top category I want to show a specific list of categories:

I know that I can get the current category ID with this code:

```
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
```

But then how can I check that category ID is a descendant of a specific top parent category:

```
  <?php if (.....) { ?> 
      <?php wp_list_categories('orderby=id&show_count=0&use_desc_for_title=0&child_of='.$men->term_id); ?>
                      <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `category_parent` property to get the ID of the parent, and then the `get_the_category()` function to load it, or determine if it is the one you want. For multiple levels you would need to use recursion.

```
$category_id = get_query_var('cat');
$category    = get_the_category( $category_id );
$parent_id   = $category[0]->category_parent;
$parent      = get_the_category( $parent_id );
```

Comment: **`get_category`**  instead of **`get_the_category`**